# Python Headless Chrome Slows Tests by 20x

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I have written a test program that performs tests on websites. I am trying to run my tests in headless Chrome using the `--headless` argument. While it works fine in a normal browser window, it runs 20 times slower in headless mode. Are there different alternatives you can suggest for Windows? Chrome headless is unfortunately very unstable.

These are the arguments I use

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-features=TranslateUI')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-agent=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
chrome_options.add_argument("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1366,728")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
```

Answer (score 1):

The Chromium developers recently added a **2nd** headless mode (in 2021). See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

They later renamed the option in 2023 for Chrome 109 -> https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/e9c516118e2e1923757ecb13e6d9fff36775d1f4

For Chrome 109 and above, the `--headless=new` flag will now allow you to get the full functionality of Chrome in the new headless mode, and you can even run extensions in it. (For Chrome versions 96 through 108, use `--headless=chrome`)

Usage: (Chrome 109 and above):

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

Usage: (Chrome 96 through Chrome 108):

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=chrome")
```

If something works in regular Chrome, it should now work with the newer headless mode too.